# Authentication methods over sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to get authentication working over sockets with `sailsjs` and `passport`.

The challenge seems to be the fact that a socket connection doesn't have a session, and that sailsjs mocks a request object, causing it to not have Passport middleware setup. This caused nodejs to throw an error, saying that the `req` object didn't have a method called `logIn`.

So, I've tried following the code snippet as provided by @xdissent here: [Sails.js + Passport.js authentication through websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365444/sails-js-passport-js-authentication-through-websockets) which, indeed allows me to sign in without throwing errors. Or does it..? It turns out that it does *something*, But I have no idea what. Because upon fetching `req.user` through a different (socket) request, I get an empty object returned.

I've looked in redis, too. This came out of it:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "waterline:broadcasting:_sequences:id"
2) "sess:aDJI0YHzh17E3AMjtKsZSijs"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get "sess:aDJI0YHzh17E3AMjtKsZSijs"
"{\"cookie\":{\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

So there is a session, just no user stored in it.

So long story short, how do I get Passport and sailsjs to play nice over sockets.

**Update**:
I'd like some information about sessions, sockets and cookies with sails in general. So if I set stuff in a session, and refresh the browser, I'd like it to still be there. If I make an xhr call on the same page as the socket connection, shouldn't that be the same session?

Comment: upvoting this as its a good question that i've yet to figure out an answer for.

Comment: +1 Did you already found a solution to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio

Comment: Did you implement serializeUser and deserializeUser?

Comment: @Jason Nichols passport.socketio will not implement the passport request methods Wesley ask for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [Kasper Isager](https://github.com/kasperisager) there will be a passport generator for sails.js in the near future (Sails.js Version 0.10).

He implement Passport by using policies (sails middleware).

*api/services/passport.js*

```
var passport = require('passport');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, next) {
    next(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, next) {
    User.findOne(id).done(next);
});

// Put your Passport config logic here

// Make passport globally available
module.exports = passport;
```

*api/policies/passport.js*

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

  // Initialize Passport
  passport.initialize()(req, res, function () {
    // Use the built-in sessions
    passport.session()(req, res, function () {
      // Make the user available throughout the frontend
      res.locals.user = req.user;

      next();
    });
  });

};
```

*config/policies.js*

```
module.exports.policies = {

    '*': [ 'passport' ],

    // MyCustomController: {
    //  update: [
    //      'passport',
    //      'authorize'
    //  ]
    // }

};
```

This will make the the passport request methods (logIn, etc.) available in socket requests as well.

After a successful login your server-side session object will look like this:

```
{
    // Express
    cookie: {
        originalMaxAge: null,
        expires: null,
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/'
    },
    // Passport
    passport: {
        user: '52fc98e108b31348a537fa43' // userId
    }
}
```

You may access it in any policy with `req.session` or even on socket callbacks like:

*config/sockets.js*

```
onConnect: function(session, socket){}
onDisconnect: function(session, socket){}
```

If you want to see the Kaspers full implementation check out his repository:
[sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth)

Comment: I might misunderstand how passport works, but shouldn't `passport.serializeUser` and deserialize be done in the service? otherwise we are re-declaring the (de)serialization functions at every request?

Comment: Thanks for sharing w/ everyone (and of course thanks to Kasper).  This is excellent.

Comment: @Hudon Yes I guess you are right. Both works but your way is better since ```serializeUser``` and ```deserializeUser``` is only initialized once.

Comment: Does this method (not the generate) work with 0.9.x?

Comment: Followed this and set everything up the same way.  I stepped through to ensure the policies were running, but I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'logIn'`

Comment: if ```req.logIn``` is not set you probably haven't included the ```passport```-policy. You Policies file should look similar to this:
```...'*':['passport'], MyContr: {find: ['passport','authorize']}...```

Comment: That is there, the policy runs.  It puts a `_passport` object on the req, but none of the methods (like `logIn`)

Comment: I configured 2 different ones (local and SAML).  I ended up going with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365444/sails-js-passport-js-authentication-through-websockets/18343226#18343226 and it solved the problem with the socket req not having the methods.

Comment: @HaNdTriX: I followed your steps above, but it didn't work. Error is `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'logIn'`.

Comment: @anhnt check out: https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/blob/master/templates/api/controllers/AuthController.js

Comment: @HaNdTriX this is my passport.js in api/services/passport.js. Seem there is no User model here :( https://gist.github.com/anhnt/e59c4e8180ffc294d0ee

Comment: Just for the record: sails-generate-auth doesn't create a user model for you. You have to create it on your own and set up the passport model as a role.

Comment: Great answer, all my other policies works as before (when I only used HTTP requests) without any change to them!