# Use express-validator as a middleware with websockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, express-validator

I used [Sails.js + Passport.js authentication through websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17365444/2545889) to bind passport.js methods for requests through websockets (using sockets.io) , but how should i add [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) methods to ensure that all requests have methods from it

Comment: Do you have any example code that you need express-validator to work with?

Comment: `updateMinimumAmount: (req, res) => {
    req.assert('schemeId', 'schemeId should be integer').notEmpty().isInt();`
When this method is called from sockets instead making a http request , i am getting req.assert notfound but not the case if i call it with a http request

Comment: Can you post your code in question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using customMiddleware by adding 'express-validator' in the `config/http.js`:

```
order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'expressValidator',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      //'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
],

expressValidator: require('express-validator')()
```

This should get you express validator and you can import and use it.

Hope it solves your query.

Comment: But i don't think it will still be included in socket requests right , sockets request doesn't pass http.js for middleware , as i mentioned in the question the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365444/sails-js-passport-js-authentication-through-websockets) helped me to include passport which i wrote in a new file called bindpassport_boot.js and kept it in app/boot . How can i do something similar for other libraries

Comment: Hi @Jack , I tried this solution and as i said above it doesn't have any effect . Any API call as http are getting the methods from express-validator but still API calls from sockets(using [socke.io](https://socket.io/)) still doesn't get the methods

Comment: How did you import them now?

Comment: I shifted things to http requests and removed socket requests

Comment: Lets do some digging for the sockets and sails.